# How can I convert this input in a number with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I haven't been able to find the right conversion to a decimal number, from a field declared as varchar.

Oracle 12c

The source info said they set this format:
'S9999999999999V,99'

I used TO_NUMBER() function, but cant find the correct cast and arguments to read and convert properly the source.

With only TO_NUMBER(field) send and invalid number error.

Data received examples

1. +0000000000160,00
2. -9999999999999,99

I keep receiving the invalid number error.

Comment: Are you sure about the V in the format? And what values are you expecting those two examples to convert to: 160 and -9999999999999.99?

Comment: about the format, yes, that is what i received  in the documentation from the source Team, the 99999 is a Test Data they sent, is not as relevant, but I think the to_number should be able to convert it as well.

The 160,00 is what I would expect.

Comment: Hmm. Did they say what the V meant to them? Not sure it makes sense, or is legal, with `V,99`

Comment: When you get an error message, please cut & paste the entire message rather than paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The V in the source info format doesn't look right; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C):

> | Element | Example | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | V | 999V99 | Returns a value multiplied by 10n (and if necessary, round it up), where n is the number of 9's after the V. |

If the rest of the model is right, and it seems be as it matches the two examples, then you probably want:

```
to_number(source, 'S9999999999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.')
```

The `fmt` part is the same as you were told, just with V removed, and with D to mark the decimal separator; and the `nls` part says that the decimal separator is a comma.

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (source) as (
  select '+0000000000160,00' from dual
  union all
  select '-9999999999999,99' from dual
)
-- query against sample data
select source,
  to_number(source, 'S9999999999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.') as result
from your_table
```

gives

```
SOURCE            RESULT
----------------- -----------------
+0000000000160,00               160
-9999999999999,99 -9999999999999.99
```

The client will choose whether to display the converted value with a comma or period decimal separator, usually via NLS settings. You can change that session setting, or explicitly convert the number back to a string in a specific format.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0f98dabfcee5ea535b2b88b54d0fbb26) showing default and modified session output.